# Meteor & Backbone Sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor

I search best way to sync my Backbone.Collection and Meteor MongoDB Collection.
What a best way for it? I want make POST/GET request thru the client.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor already keeps your server collections and client-side cached collections in sync. If you wish to use backbone.js collections, you can do it in two ways.

First way: use an observe on MongoDB cursor, look for all 'added', 'changed' and 'removed' events and deal with them however you want. More in [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe).

Second way: to keep memory consumption lower and not keep two copies of every object in both Minimongo and Backbone collections, you can go one level lower and use `registerStore` - client-side DDP API.

For API docs look at the [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js#L391). Also [DDP specs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md) can help, look at "Managing Data" section.